# user control datagrid checkbox are coming disabled by default

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am loading a user control in a `div` at run time having a grid but when loading checkboxes in data grid coming diabled

My code

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="proccessLetters" GridLines="horizontal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ShowFooter="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0"
        Font-Name="Arial" Font-Size="13px" ItemStyle-BackColor="#FFFFFF" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#ebc6c6"
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7F0037">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="220" HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input type="checkbox" disabled="false"   value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Let_Id").ToString()%>">
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-Width="250" HeaderText="Document Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Document_Name").ToString()%>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="100" DataField="Doc_Id" Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText=""></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="100" DataField="Off_Id" Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText=""></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="100" DataField="Off_Name" Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText=""></asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: what should i do to make check boxes enabled

Comment: try using <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />

Comment: not working my user control does not has form tag and it is working under form tag only

Comment: I'd just get rid of the disabled tag. Disabled="false" will not enable your <input> tag .. the attribute value "expected" for disabled is disabled="disabled" not false. @Junaid is correct.

Comment: thats ok but what is the solution for that

Answer (score 0):

did you try removing disabled attribute from the checkbox? also any reason of not using asp.net checkbox control?

Comment: not working my user control does not has form tag and it is working under form tag only